# Firebase hosting using SvelteKit

Tags: firebase, svelte, firebase-hosting, sveltekit, svelte-3

I have created a svelte app and building app using SvelteKit everything is works fine.

I tried to deploy this app in firebase hosting but it fails. Sveltekit generating production build under `.svelte-kit` folder. I tried to change the `public` object value to `".svelte-kit"` from `firebase.json` file but it returns error like there is no index.html and 404.html. What we need to change in `firebase.json` to make it work?

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public" : "public",

    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using SSR? Then this might be of interest https://github.com/jthegedus/svelte-adapter-firebase (You might add the info which adapter you are using)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While building svelte app for production we can configure build location to public using `svelte.config.js` file

```
   import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: [
        preprocess({
          postcss: true,
        }),
      ],

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'public',
            assets: 'public',
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false
            }),
            prerender: {
            default: true
            }
    }
};

export default config;
```

Here we should use `@sveltejs/adapter-static` adapter to build.

No need to change `firebase.json` we can leave it as it is

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public" : "public",

    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Firebase Hosting now supports Sveltekit natively (Beta). Unfortunately, the current state of documentation is not amazing :) The setup process is pretty straight forward though and there is no need to use the adapters anymore.

I wrote a short Gist on how I did install it on Firebase Hosting and added a few links to useful docs: https://gist.github.com/coehne/caf0b3934455d842dfbfe1f4c1544348

Answer (score 3):

I have built an adapter for firebase which enables SSR for Firebase and supports CloudFunctions v2 for concurrency:
[sveltekit-adapter-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sveltekit-adapter-firebase)

Comment: Hi, I'm starting a new project. Is there a difference between your adapter and [svelte-adapter-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-adapter-firebase)?

Comment: @JanB
My adapter generates the cloud function for you while in the other adapter you have to take care of that file yourself. In the grand scheme of things I'd say my adapter is simpler the use while the other one offers you more flexibility