# How to host a sveltekit app with routes (+server.js) in a Firebase hosting or functions environment?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, sveltekit

Firebase requires functions to be written under the `functions` folder, on the other hand, Sveltekit asks server APIs to be in +server.js files under the `routes` folder.

I'm struggling to get this to work. I suppose I should be using the `@sveltejs/adapter-node`  adapter, but then do I have to initiate an `express server` somewhere for Firebase to handle the API routes correctly?

Doing my research, I found people on SO usually only use [static adapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73282472/firebase-hosting-using-sveltekit)

p.s: I found [this project](https://github.com/ManuelDeLeon/sveltekit-firebase-ssr) that seems to achieve this, but it's still not clear how he deployed it.

Comment: Have you gone through this [blog](https://rishi.app/blog/using-firebase-admin-with-sveltekit) which is using Firebase Admin with SvelteKit

Comment: Thanks for the link, actually it doesn't work as firebase hosting does not run as a nodejs app and will not load index.js

Comment: check this [svelte-adapter-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-adapter-firebase) and  try with different version of sveltekit also have a look at this  stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70750601/sveltekit-firebase-hosting/70761896#70761896)

Comment: Thank you, there's plenty of info in your links. I'll try that and reach back to say if it worked.